# Probability of selecting consecutive floors in an elevator - Error in logic

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Three people get into an empty elevator at the first floor of a building that has 10 floors. Each presses the button for their desired floor (unless one of the others has already pressed the button). Assume that they are equally likely to want to go to floors 2 through 10 (independently of each other). What is the probability that the buttons for 3 consecutive floors are pressed? (question from 'introduction to probability' by Bliztstein)

I understand that the event for this question is given by 7*3! and the sample space is given by 9^3.

However, in my first attempt, I considered the sum of the following 3 cases for the sample space:
Case 1) Person A, B, and C all go to the same floor. Therefore the number of choices = 9
Case 2) Two persons(eg A, B) go to the same floor and person C goes to a different floor. Therefore the number of choices are 9*1*8 = 72
Case 3) A, B, and C all go to different floors. Therefore number of choices are 9*8*7 = 504
Hence the sample space totals to 9 + 72 + 504 = 585.

Can someone please explain the mistake in my logic?

Comment: For case $2$ you neglect the fact that the pair of people who go to the same floor can be chosen in three ways.

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was already pointed out in a comment, you neglected the fact that 3 people .can be split in a doublet and singlet in three different ways. Therefore the complete sample space is:
$$9+3\cdot 72+504=729=9^3.
$$